# how to lose focus on a text field when I press enter or anywhere else on the screen?

Tags: android

My scenario is as it follows: I have a search fragment and in that fragment, I have 3 text fields(Search by name, by zip code and by distance). When the focus is applied on the "Search by name" field, the other 2 fields dissapear and the width of the selected field increases. My problem is that I can't lose focus of the first field and so, after I am done with writing the information, I can't use the other 2 fields.

What I am looking for is a way to lose focus of the fields when I press "enter" or when I press anywhere else on the screen but the text field.

Here is the code that I am running right now:

```
final EditText searchByName = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.search_by_name);
    final EditText searchByZipcode = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.search_by_zipcode);
    final EditText searchByDistance = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.search_by_distance);
searchByName.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    /* When focus is lost check that the text field
    * has valid values.
    */
            if (hasFocus) {
                searchByName.getLayoutParams().width=900;
                searchByZipcode.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                searchByDistance.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else {
                searchByName.getLayoutParams().width=405;
                searchByZipcode.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                searchByDistance.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });

    searchByZipcode.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    /* When focus is lost check that the text field
    * has valid values.
    */
            if (hasFocus) {
                searchByZipcode.getLayoutParams().width=700;
                searchByName.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else {
                searchByZipcode.getLayoutParams().width=240;
                searchByName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Inside your Activity Class , add this below method** , it will work for you .It will hide keyboard and will clear focus anywhere outside you click in that one it will work .

```
  @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.
                INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        return true;
    }
```